# Why does CAST() not work correctly in MySQL functions?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_rule (value TEXT, greater_than DECIMAL(10,4))
RETURNS BOOL
RETURN greater_than IS NULL OR CAST(value AS DECIMAL(10,4)) > greater_than;
```

If I use this function with an empty string vor `value` I receive an error:

```
SELECT test_rule('',10)
```

> (1366): Incorrect decimal value: '' for column '' at row -1

But the same expression works fine without a function:

```
SELECT '' IS NULL OR CAST('' AS DECIMAL(10,4)) > 10
```

> 0

Why is this?

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.22

Comment: I tried both expressions in Toad for MySQL (5.6.17) and they work fine.

Comment: Both work for me,  MySQL 5.6.28

Comment: That's very weird. I wonder if it has something to do with [adminer](www.adminer.org), which I used to test the above.

Comment: Can you check what the sql_mode setting is on the server? Try setting the sql mode to '' (empty string) for the session and execute the stored proc again.

Comment: Also can you pls check what sql mode applies to the stored function by getting the function's sql_mode value from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table?

Comment: Your input value type TEXT is not strictly the same as the empty string ''. Have you tried creating the function with VARCHAR instead of TEXT?

Comment: @Shadow `sql_mode` was `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. I've changed it to `''` and it really seems to work now. I still somehow get the same error when calling the function from a trigger, though. But that's probably a different problem. The example above was already simplified a bit. Maybe you want to elaborate a bit in an answer below?

Comment: @Shadow I've recreated everything including the triggers and my error is gone now. The question is: Can I change the `sql_mode` on a per function/trigger basis? And if so, how?

Comment: I prepared a detailed answer, let me know if sg is still unclear.

Comment: Use `CONVERT` instead of `CAST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way mysql handles certain data conversions is also affected by the [sql mode settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) (see Strict SQL Mode section in particular) and [CAST functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

The documentation is a bit hazy on how these restrictions apply in an expression evaluation, however the CAST function documentation does mention that

> The SQL mode affects the result of conversion operations.

The OP mentioned in a comment that `sql_mode` is set to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` means that strict sql mode is enabled for transactional tables and probably for cast operations as well.

`''` (empty string) cannot be properly casted to a number. If strict sql mode is not enabled, then mysql generates a warning and evaluates `''` with the default value for the given numeric type - 0 that is. However, if strict sql mode is enabled, such conversion results in an error.

You can change the sql mode on global or session level by setting the appropriate value to sql_mode variable.

There is one more complication with stored programs. Stored programs run with the sql mode setting valid at [compile time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html):

> MySQL stores the sql_mode system variable setting in effect when a
>   routine is created or altered, and always executes the routine with
>   this setting in force, regardless of the current server SQL mode when
>   the routine begins executing.

If you want different stored procedures to run under different sql mode settings, then

1. drop the existing stored routine
2. change the sql mode to the desired setting
3. re-create the stored program

You can query the sql mode setting for any stored routine by listing INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table (sql_mode column).

However, I would consider re-writing the code in this particular instance so that it checks if the value parameter equals with `''` empty string, rather than starting to play with the sql mode settings. The problem is that these special sql mode setting requirements can be easily forgotten or overlooked during system change or migration and the existing code may start throwing errors around and it will be difficult to re-trace the source of the issues.

Comment: Thanks. I've also tried to make my code work with empty strings `''` first - but it still failed. So I gave up and now have a working solution where I create the routines after a `SET SESSION sql_mode='';`. This seems to do the trick.

Comment: Then make sure this is properly documented within the code and in the operating guide as well. Had a case when an application was migrated, but these particualarities were not noted. It was quite painful to debug all stored routines and identift which of them required a different sql mode setting.